# compare the int in the strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my code as I want to compare the int in the strings on a if statement to see if the value is equal or greater than.

When I try this:

```
for prog_clock, prog_length, pos_X, prog_ids in izip_longest(program_clock, programs_length, posX, progId, fillvalue=''):
    epg_time_1 = self.getControl(344).getLabel()
    epg_time_2 = self.getControl(345).getLabel()
    epg_time_3 = self.getControl(346).getLabel()


    if int(pos_X) == 375:
       for program_id, program_length, program_minutes in zip(prog_id_list, programs_length, program_remaining):

           if epg_time_2 == prog_clock:
              print "WORKING 1"

           elif prog_clock > epg_time_1 and epg_time_2 > prog_clock:
              print "WORKING 2"


           elif epg_time_3 == prog_clock:
              print "WORKING 3"


           elif epg_time_3 < prog_clock:
               print "WORKING 4"
```

Output for `prog_clock`:

```
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 11:00PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:00PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:00PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:45PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 11:05PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:00PM
21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:00PM
```

Output for epg_time_1:

```
9:30PM
```

Output for epg_time_2:

```
10:00PM
```

Output for epg_time_3:

```
10:30PM
```

I want to compare three strings from the object strings with each of the `prog_clock` string to see which if statement I can get pass for each of these string for the tv program. When I try to compare them, it won't let me to get pass on any of these if statement. So how I can compare the int in the strings to see if the value is equal or greater than?

Comment: Since you are working with timestamps here wouldn't it be better to parse that part exclusively as time and then (using Python's functionality such as `datetime.strptime`) compare the stamps?

Comment: yes of course i am working on it so would it better if i should use `datetime.strptime` or what?

Comment: Well, when you have to tools I don't see why not use these. :P Since each line consists of two timestamps at a very specific location (namely 1)beginning to first space and then 2)last space to end of line) you can easily get these chunks and do the magic of parsing and doing whatever you want to with these.

Comment: can you post an answer how i can do that? :)

Comment: Sure, will do that in a moment.

Comment: Btw `21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 11:00PM` is what we have to work with right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the strings are identical, comparing them directly should work

```
string1 = '10:00PM'
string2 = '11:00PM'

print(string2 > string1)

print(string1 > string2)
```

outputs

```
True
False
```

EDIT: After reading the comments, i decided to edit my answer and post a solution with `time.strptime`

```
from time import strptime

format = '%I:%M%p' # format to striptime

epg_time_1 = strptime('9:30PM', format)
epg_time_2 = strptime('10:10PM', format)
epg_time_3 = strptime('10:30PM', format)


prog_clock = strptime('10:00PM', format)

if epg_time_2 == prog_clock:
    print("WORKING 1")

elif prog_clock > epg_time_1 and epg_time_2 > prog_clock:
    print("WORKING 2")


elif epg_time_3 == prog_clock:
    print("WORKING 3")


elif epg_time_3 < prog_clock:
    print("WORKING 4")
```

Outputs `"WORKING 2"`

Comment: what about if statement if they are equal or greater than?

Comment: The reason it dosen't work is because strings are compared lexographically i.e it compares the first element so `10:00PM` will be less than `9:30PM` i.e 1 is less than 9. this could be fixed by just making it `09:30PM`...but i guess you don't want that

Comment: This is wrong. Apart from glossing over the parsing of `prog_clock` to a time value, the `strptime()` format string assumes 24 hour format which causes `strptime()` to ignore the AM/PM. e.g. `strptime('10:00PM', '%H:%M%p').tm_hour` == 10 which is 10am, not 10pm. The correct format string is `'%I:%M%p'`:  `strptime('10:00PM', '%I:%M%p').tm_hour` == 22, which _is_ 10pm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for each line you can apply the function `parseLine(str)` from below. What I'm doing is basically the following:

For a given line (for example: `21:41:45 T:5796  NOTICE: 10:00PM`) I

1. Get the first timestamp, which we know that is of the format `HH:MM:SS`
2. Get the second timestamp, which we know that is of the format `HH:MM(AM/PM)`
3. Convert both to time objects (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects))
4. Compare

Of course you can adjust the format according to the format of a line (in case you decide to change it). The important thing is to convert the timestamps correctly since the first one is using the 24 hour format but the second one - the 12 hour format (I use `%I` to convert the hour-part of the second timestamp to 24 hour format so that we can easily compare both). The comparison itself is done by Python and the time objects, which support it. Also I assumed that both of your timestamps use space as a separator from the middle sub-string but in case the first one is separated by a tabulator you can change the delimiter option of `split()` from `' '` to `'\t'`.

```
from datetime import datetime

def parseLine(line):
  # Use split() and rsplit() to get the stamps
  # Extract the first timestamp - it is separated from the rest by the first space in your string
  first_tstamp = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
  # Extract the second timestamp - it is separated from the rest by the last space in your string
  last_tstamp = line.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]

  # Parse the string representations of both stamps to a time object
  t_first = datetime.strptime(first_tstamp, "%H:%M:%S").time()  # Format: HH:MM:SS
  t_second = datetime.strptime(last_tstamp, "%I:%M%p").time() # Format: HH:MM(PM/AM)

  print("FIRST",t_first)
  print("SECOND",t_second)

  if(t_first > t_second): return 1
  elif(t_first < t_second): return -1
  else: return 0

def test(line):
  res = parseLine(line)

  if(res > 0): print("FIRST later than LAST")
  elif(res < 0): print("FIRST earlier than LAST")
  else: print("FIRST same as LAST")

print("--------Test 1--------")
# First is earlier than second  
test("21:41:45 T:5796 NOTICE: 11:00PM")
print("--------Test 2--------")
# First is later than second
test("12:05:30 T:5796 NOTICE: 10:00AM")
print("--------Test 3--------")
# First is same as second
test("23:00:00 T:5796 NOTICE: 11:00PM")
```

There are actually multiple solutions for this and this might not be the best one but it does the trick. The output of the test I'm doing at the end is:

```
FIRST earlier than LAST # Because 21 is less than 11PM (=23)
FIRST later than LAST   # Because 12 is greater than 10AM (=10)
FIRST same as LAST      # Because 23 is the same as 11PM (=23)
```

Comment: Ah, the parsing is not required. Never mind than. You have already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For `prog_clock` extract the time component from the string, parse it using `datetime.strptime()` and convert it to a `datetime.time` object. Now you can compare the times directly. Just add the four lines to parse the input as shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime

for prog_clock, prog_length, pos_X, prog_ids in izip_longest(program_clock, programs_length, posX, progId, fillvalue=''):
    epg_time_1 = self.getControl(344).getLabel()
    epg_time_2 = self.getControl(345).getLabel()
    epg_time_3 = self.getControl(346).getLabel()

    # parse time data into datetime.time objects for comparison
    prog_clock = datetime.strptime(prog_clock.split()[-1], '%I:%M%p').time()
    epg_time_1 = datetime.strptime(epg_time_1, '%I:%M%p').time()
    epg_time_2 = datetime.strptime(epg_time_2, '%I:%M%p').time()
    epg_time_2 = datetime.strptime(epg_time_3, '%I:%M%p').time()

    ...
```

Actually, converting to `datetime.time` objects is optional - if you omit it the `datetime.datetime` values will all have the same date (1900-01-01), and the time comparisons will still work anyway.